# every time i refresh my page php adding record to databse

Tags: php

```
    <html>
    <title>Certification</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Muscat");
    //echo date_default_timezone_get();
    ?>


    <?php
    include('connect-db.php');
    $Id = $_GET['Id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master WHERE IDM=$Id")

    or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $Asset_Number = $row['Asset_number'];
    $Description2 = $row['Description2'];
    $Parent_Verified = $row['Parent_Verified'];
    $Make=$row['Make'];
    $Model=$row['Model'];
    $Serial_Number=$row['Serial_Number'];
    $Associated_with=$row['Associated_with'];
    $Comment=$row['Comment'];
    $Date_of_Manufacture=$row['Date_of_Manufacture'];
    $Unit=$row['Physically_Verified_Location'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])!=""){

      $name1=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
      $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
      $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
      $temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
      $ext = end((explode(".", $name1)));
      $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $caption1=$_POST['caption'];
      $link=$_POST['link'];
      $Inspection_type = $_POST['Inspection_type'];
      $Inspection_comp = $_POST['Inspection_comp'];
      $Inspection_Date = $_POST['Inspection_Date'];
      $Expiry_Date = $_POST['Expiry_Date'];
      $name = $Asset_Number.'-'.$Inspection_type.'-'.$Inspection_comp.'-'.$Inspection_Date.'-'.$Expiry_Date.'.' . end(explode(".",$_FILES['photo']['name']));

      move_uploaded_file($temp,"/files/".$name);



    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload (name,date,Asset_Number,Serial_Number,Inspection_type,Inspection_comp,Inspection_Date,Expiry_Date,id_m)VALUES ('$name','$date','$Asset_Number','$Asset_sno','$Inspection_type','$Inspection_comp','$Inspection_Date','$Expiry_Date','$Id')"))
    {
    header('location:certificate.php');
    Exit;

    }


    else{
    die(mysql_error());
    }
    }
    ?>






    <html>


    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#WellCAT td.exdate').each(function(){
            if ($(this).text() ==cal.getTime();') {
                $(this).css('background-color','#ff9933');
            }
            else $(this).css('background-color','#99ccff');
        });
    });

    </script>







    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
               <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
               <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>


                                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:#33ccff;">
                        <H4><U><CENTER>CERTIFICATE UPDATE</CENTER></U> </H1>

    </div>



                                  </head>                           

      <body>                     





    <div class="container fluid">
     <div class="row">
    <form class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="" id="wb_Form1" name="form" method="post">





    <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<?php echo $Id; ?>"/>
     <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <label class="form-control">ID</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Id; ?></label><br>
    <label class="form-control">Asset Number</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Asset_Number; ?></label><br>
    <label class="form-control">Description</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Description2; ?></label><br>
    <label class="form-control">Parent</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Parent_Verified; ?></label><br>
    <label class="form-control">Make</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Make; ?></label><br>
    <label class="form-control">Model</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Model; ?></label><br>
    <label class="form-control">Serial Number</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Serial_Number; ?></label><br></div>
     <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;"><br><br>
    <label class="form-control">Associated with</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Associated_with; ?></label><br>
    <label class="form-control">Comment</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Comment; ?></label><br>
    <label class="form-control">Date of Manufacture</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Date_of_Manufacture; ?></label><br>
    <label class="form-control">Unit</label><label class="form-control"><?php echo $Unit; ?></label><br></div>


     <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <br><br>
    <label class="form-control">Inspection type</label><select class="form-control" name="Inspection_type" required="required"> <option value=""></option><br>
                                                                    <option value="Major">Major Inspection</option>
                                                                    <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate Inspection</option>
                                                                    <option value="Other">Other Inspection</option>
                                                                    </select>


    <label class="form-control">Inspection Company</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Inspection_comp"><br>
    <label class="form-control">Inspection Date</label><input type="date" class="form-control" name="Inspection_Date"><br>
    <label class="form-control">Expiry Date</label><input type="date" class="form-control" name="Expiry_Date">

        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
     Please choose file here.....(Maximum allowed file size 10Mb)
    </div>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control"name="photo" id="photo"  required="required">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="SUBMIT" name="submit">
    </div>

    </form>


    </div>
    </div>










                                 <div class="col-md-18">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;">
       <div class = "row">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">


                                <form method="post" action="deletefile.php" >
                             <table id="WellCAT" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed" id="example">

                                <thead>

                                    <tr>

                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Asset Number</th>
                                        <th>Inspection Type</th>
                                        <th>Inspection Company</th>
                                        <th>Inspection Date</th>
                                        <th>Expiry Date</th>
                                        <th>FILE NAME</th>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>Download</th>
                                        <th>Remove</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $query=mysql_query("select * from upload WHERE id_m=$Id")or die(mysql_error());
                                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                                $id=$row['id'];

                                $Asset_Number=$row['Asset_Number'];
                                $Inspection_type=$row['Inspection_type'];
                                $Inspection_comp=$row['Inspection_comp'];
                                $Inspection_Date=$row['Inspection_Date'];
                                $Expiry_Date=$row['Expiry_Date'];
                                $name=$row['name'];
                                $date=$row['date'];
                                ?>

                                            <tr>

                                             <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                                             <td><?php echo $row['Asset_Number'] ?></td>
                                             <td><?php echo $row['Inspection_type'] ?></td>
                                             <td><?php echo $row['Inspection_comp'] ?></td>
                                             <td><?php echo $row['Inspection_Date'] ?></td>
                                             <td><?php echo $row['Expiry_Date'] ?></td> 
                                             <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                                             <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
                                            <td>
                    <a href="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name;?>" title="click to download"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip" style="font-size:20px; color:blue"></span></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <a href="deletefile.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="font-size:20px; color:red"></span></a>
                    </td>
                                    </tr>

                                      <?php } ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>




                                </div>

    </form>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </body>
    </html>
    <script>  
     $(document).ready(function(){  
          $('#WellCAT').DataTable();  
     });  
     </script>
```

I have two issues.. 
1 - Every time refresh my page the code is uploading a same date to the table.
I have tried redirecting to header location to header... but it still having the same issue.. 
2 - When i am moving the this file (file upload.php) to another folder in my directory, the downloading function will not work.

Comment: You should do something with the way you're handling the connection to the DB because this code is a ticking time bomb waiting to get haked by [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), read about PDO and prepereded stetments [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in order to addresss those huge issues

Comment: @Siji the way you are linking to your `download.php` is the reason why it stops working when this file is moved inside a folder. Read about relative and absolute links. `href="download.php"` tells the browser that `download.php` is in the same folder as this file. You'll need to update your link after you move your page or also move the download.php to the new folder. The same applies to how you fetch the files to be downloaded inside your `download.php` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your condition is wrong.

Change the condition to do this.

From:
`if(isset($_POST['submit'])!=""){`

To:
`if(isset($_POST['submit')){`

Comment: Changed to 
if(isset($_POST['submit')){ but still the same issue

Comment: @Siji While reloading, does the browser show an alert box asking to resubmit values?

Comment: Does it mean it still gets the record populated in the database?

Comment: @JaswinderSingh I feel the same. Suggest siji to open a new tab to test maybe?

Comment: @JaswinderSingh Yes, it is asking for "confirm for re submission"

Comment: Then suggest you to test it in new tab or new browser window.

Comment: @Siji pressing ok on the alert will resubmit the form with all the input values, as the browser will redo everything it did the first time. Btw why r u refreshing that page manually using browser?

Comment: But when i move my upload and down load file to inside folder, i am able to upload file, but the download code is not working, it says file not found.. :(

Answer (score 1):

`isset` function return `true` or `false` depend on the variable is set or not.

in your code `if(isset($_POST['submit'])!="")` is checking is submit of post is set , which return false, then you try to compare with not equal empty string , which return true ..

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])!="")
if(false != "") // isset($_POST['submit']) , when post is not set 
if(true)
```

I think you get the point ..

you can do by checking is post of submit set or not, do not need any extra logic

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'))
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing following line:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])!="")
```

To:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] != ""){
```